# System.QueryException: line 1:873 no viable alternative at character ')'

Tags: apex

Getting error in this query:

```
String soql = 'SELECT Id, Name, Search_Request_Date__c, Name_to_Search_First__c, Name_to_Search_Middle__c, Name_to_Search_Last__c, Date_of_Birth__c, Search_Type_Name__c, Account__r.Name, Account__r.State_Providence__r.Abbreviation__c, Applicant_State__c, Researcher__r.Name, Jurisdiction_Name__c, Notes_Internal__c, IsFollowUp__c FROM Background_Search__c WHERE IT_testing_account__c = false AND Status_Standard__c = \'Pending\' AND Status_Standard__c != null AND Internal__c != \'External\' AND Jurisdiction__r.Distribution_Group_Name__c =:'+ sGroupJurisdictionName+' AND  Ready_For_Internal_Processing__c = true AND Jurisdiction__r.Active_Jurisdiction__c = true AND Jurisdiction__r.Research_Level__c <= '+ sUserLevel+'  AND Jurisdiction__r.Distribute_by_Group__c = true AND Record_Locked__c = false AND ( IsFollowUp__c = false OR (IsFollowUp__c = true AND Follow_Up_Date__c != null AND Follow_Up_Date__c <= '+System.now().date()+') ) ';
            if(!isCompliance){
              soql = soql +'AND Type__c != \'RAA Change Audit\' AND Type__c != \'Needs clarifications Search\' AND Type__c != \'Adjudication\' ';
            }
            soql = soql + 'ORDER BY Distribution_Score__c DESC, Search_Age__c, Jurisdiction__c, Jurisdiction__r.Distribution_Group_Name__c, PreEmploy_Case__c LIMIT '+iNextLimit+'';
            System.debug('Gaurav'+soql);
            lstSearchForDistribution = Database.query(soql);
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you can bind variable inside the SOQL without having to take them outside of the string so try this:

You also can change the date to be an SOQL Literal of TODAY.

You also had an extra ' at the end of one of the lines:

```
String soql = 'SELECT Id, Name, Search_Request_Date__c, Name_to_Search_First__c, Name_to_Search_Middle__c, Name_to_Search_Last__c, Date_of_Birth__c, Search_Type_Name__c, Account__r.Name, Account__r.State_Providence__r.Abbreviation__c, Applicant_State__c, Researcher__r.Name, Jurisdiction_Name__c, Notes_Internal__c, IsFollowUp__c FROM Background_Search__c WHERE IT_testing_account__c = false AND Status_Standard__c = \'Pending\' AND Status_Standard__c != null AND Internal__c != \'External\' AND Jurisdiction__r.Distribution_Group_Name__c = :sGroupJurisdictionName AND  Ready_For_Internal_Processing__c = true AND Jurisdiction__r.Active_Jurisdiction__c = true AND Jurisdiction__r.Research_Level__c <= :sUserLevel AND Jurisdiction__r.Distribute_by_Group__c = true AND Record_Locked__c = false AND ( IsFollowUp__c = false OR (IsFollowUp__c = true AND Follow_Up_Date__c != null AND Follow_Up_Date__c <= TODAY ) ) ';
            if(!isCompliance){
              soql = soql +'AND Type__c != \'RAA Change Audit\' AND Type__c != \'Needs clarifications Search\' AND Type__c != \'Adjudication\' ';
            }
            soql = soql + 'ORDER BY Distribution_Score__c DESC, Search_Age__c, Jurisdiction__c, Jurisdiction__r.Distribution_Group_Name__c, PreEmploy_Case__c LIMIT '+iNextLimit;
            System.debug('Gaurav'+soql);
            lstSearchForDistribution = Database.query(soql);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this and let me know if does not work.

```
String soql = 'SELECT Id, Name, Search_Request_Date__c, Name_to_Search_First__c, Name_to_Search_Middle__c, Name_to_Search_Last__c, Date_of_Birth__c, Search_Type_Name__c, Account__r.Name, Account__r.State_Providence__r.Abbreviation__c, Applicant_State__c, Researcher__r.Name, Jurisdiction_Name__c, Notes_Internal__c, IsFollowUp__c FROM Background_Search__c WHERE IT_testing_account__c = false AND Status_Standard__c = \'Pending\' AND Status_Standard__c != null AND Internal__c != \'External\' AND Jurisdiction__r.Distribution_Group_Name__c = '+ sGroupJurisdictionName+' AND  Ready_For_Internal_Processing__c = true AND Jurisdiction__r.Active_Jurisdiction__c = true AND Jurisdiction__r.Research_Level__c <= '+ sUserLevel+'  AND Jurisdiction__r.Distribute_by_Group__c = true AND Record_Locked__c = false AND ( IsFollowUp__c = false OR (IsFollowUp__c = true AND Follow_Up_Date__c != null AND Follow_Up_Date__c <= '+System.now().date()+') ) ';
        if(!isCompliance){
          soql = soql +'AND Type__c != \'RAA Change Audit\' AND Type__c != \'Needs clarifications Search\' AND Type__c != \'Adjudication\' ';
        }
        soql = soql + 'ORDER BY Distribution_Score__c DESC, Search_Age__c, Jurisdiction__c, Jurisdiction__r.Distribution_Group_Name__c, PreEmploy_Case__c LIMIT '+iNextLimit+'';
        System.debug('Gaurav'+soql);
        lstSearchForDistribution = Database.query(soql);
```

Comment: Getting error "Please try again.Only variable references are allowed in dynamic SOQL/SOSL."

Comment: Gaurav... I have updated the code. Could you please try again and let me know.

Comment: Getting error "Illegal assignment from Date to String at line 67 column 16"

Comment: Check you line 67 fields data type this should be date type.

Comment: String soql is Actually In line 67

Comment: You need check data type of your fields...you are assigning date to string. You can only assign date to data or string to string.